# How to load data dynamically on template?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mustache

I have this model that I have multiple instances of it in a list. I want to pass this to my UI and have the UI figure out how to draw this.

```
data class InfoModel(val icon: String, val title: String, val text: String {

}
```

The controller.

```
@GetMapping("/index")
fun start(model: Model): String {

    val list = getList()
    model ["list"] = list

    return "index"
}
```

Now in the UI I would like this to be duplicated but I don't know how.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 d-flex align-self-stretch ftco-animate">
        <div class="media block-6 services d-block text-center">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><div class="icon color-1 d-flex justify-content-center mb-3"><span class="align-self-center icon-layers"></span></div></div>
          <div class="media-body p-2">
            <h3 class="heading">Title</h3>
            <p>Text here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div>
</div>
```

---

What I tried and it doesn't display anything.

```
{{#list}}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 d-flex align-self-stretch ftco-animate">
        <div class="media block-6 services d-block text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="icon color-1 d-flex justify-content-center mb-3"><span
                        class="align-self-center icon-{{icon}}"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body p-2">
                <h3 class="heading">{{title}}</h3>
                <p>{{text}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/list}}
```

Comment: https://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/mustache.html#Non_Empty_Lists

Comment: @JBNizet that is a great link. Could you post it as an answer? I am still lost.

Comment: Try something. You chose to use Mustache as your template engine. So you need to learn its syntax, make experiments. You have a non-empty list of objects. You need to iterate over that list and repeat the same section for each element. Just like the example I linked to. So try using the same syntax and adapting it to your actual list and objects.

Comment: OK. So you're trying to display a list named "list". And for each element of the list, you're trying to display another list called "columns". But there isn't any list named columns inside InfoModel. All you have is 3 strings. Drop `{{#columns}}` and `{{/columns}}`.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet! That helped a lot! So now the content shows up stacked. So each element is on top of each other when they should be next to each out.

Comment: You forget the enclosing `<div class="row">`

Comment: Just noticed that. Hey thank you very much! I really appreciate all your help @JBNizet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to JBNizet for helping me through this. (You should post the answer, you did all the hard work).

```
{{#list}}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 d-flex align-self-stretch ftco-animate">
        <div class="media block-6 services d-block text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="icon color-1 d-flex justify-content-center mb-3"><span
                        class="align-self-center icon-{{icon}}"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body p-2">
                <h3 class="heading">{{title}}</h3>
                <p>{{text}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/list}}
```

Reference:
https://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/mustache.html#Non_Empty_Lists